# For Logistic Regression, should I avoid changing discrete independent variable to binary independent variable?

Tags: regression, logistic

I am running multiple logistic regression to understand feature importance. One of the independent variables has a distribution (histogram) that looks like:

| Value | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 4000 |
| 1 | 25 |
| 2 | 10 |
| 3 | 10 |
| 4 | 1 |

There is, obviously, a long tail here. My gut instinct is to bucket this long tail into a single value such that the distribution becomes a binary categorical variable:

| Value | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 4000 |
| Not_0 | 178 |

Is this the right instinct? I wouldn't want my coefficient from the regression to just be noise, which I anticipate the non-bucketed distribution would be susceptible to. Maybe I am misunderstand logistic regression though.

Another choice might be not using this predictor at all due to the class imbalance.

Comment: There is no assumption in logistic regression about the distribution of **independent** variables, since they are just conditioned on. So class imbalance is not an issue. For some more useful advice specific to your case, you need to tell us more specifics of your case. Specifiaclly,< whether bucketing or not depends on the goals of modeling more than statistical principles!